# How do I make WhatsApp access contacts from a specific SIM?

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger, sim-card

I have two SIM cards, one personal and the other for business. I would like WhatsApp to use contacts in the SIM card that I use for business only rather than bringing all the contacts.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can import the contacts from SIM.  Contacts are imported from your google account only.